# sitecore language selector in site header

Tags: sitecore-api, multisite

i have multi-language sitecore website and i m trying  to create a language selector in my site header to change site language .

im trying this code but not working :

```
@{
string siteurl = string.Empty;
var sitesList = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSiteInfoList();
var currentSiteName = Sitecore.Context.GetSiteName();
var website = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSite("mysite");


var myItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Item.ID, website.Language);

using (new Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextSwitcher(website))
{
    var options = LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
    options.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
    options.SiteResolving = true;
    siteurl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(myItem, options);

 <a href=@siteurl> @Sitecore.Context.Language</a>
}  

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Generate a list of URLs that go to the available languages on your site?

Comment: Can you explain what part is not working? What do you expect as your output and what is happening instead?

Also, if you have SXA, I believe there is a language selector already available for you to use.

Answer (score -1):

Try to get the my item in below way:

var myItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Item.ID, website.Language);

Comment: i try but not working